# Parsing limited switches with python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a way to parse only limited number of switches in a function using argparse? Say, my command is:

```
python sample.py -t abc -r dfg -h klm -n -p qui
```

And I want argparse to parse from -t to -h and leave the remaining, also show help for these only.
Next I want to parse any switch after -h into another function and see corresponding help there.

Is this behavior possible in argparse? Also is there a way I can modify sys.arg it is using internally?
Thanks.

Comment: You can give `parse_args` any `argv` list of strings.  For example `parse_args(sys.argv[1:5])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
python sample.py -t abc -r dfg -h klm -n -p qui
```

> And I want argparse to parse from -t to -h and leave the remaining, also show help for these only. Next I want to parse any switch after -h into another function and see corresponding help there.

There are some issues with your specification:

Is `-h` the regular help?  If so it has priority, producing the `help` without parsing the other arguments.  The string after `-h` suggests you are treating it like a normal user define argument, which would then require initiating the parser with help turned off.  But then how would you ask for `help`?

What sets the break between the two parsings/help?  The number of arguments, the `-h` flag (regardless of order), or the id of the flags.  Remember `argparse` accepts flagged arguments in any order.

You could define one parser that knows about `-t` and `-r`, and another that handles `-n` and `-p`.  Calling each with `parse_known_args` lets it operate without raising a `unknown argument` error.

You can also modify the `sys.argv`.  `parse_args` (and the known variant), takes an optional `argv` argument.  If that is none, then it uses `sys.argv[1:]`.  So you could either modify `sys.argv` itself (deleting items), or you could pass a subset of `sys.argv` to the parser.

```
parser1.parse_known_args(sys.argv[1:5])
parser2.parse_known_args(['-n','one','-o','two'])
parser3.parse_args(sys.argv[3:])
```

Play with those ideas, and come back to us if there are further questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can always modify `sys.args` and put anything you wish there.

As for your main question, you can have two parsers. One of them will have arguments `-t` to `-h`, the second `-n` and `-p`. Then you can use `argparse`'s [`parse_known_args()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) method on each parser, which will parse only the arguments defined for each of them.